# API OData no muestra valores

Tags: webservice, api, odata

Uso VS 2017, hice un web service siguiendo un tutorial, pero al ejecutarlo no trae nada de la base de datos y en su lugar muestra:

```
<ArrayOfstring>
```

value1
value2

```
public class ClienteController : ApiController        
    {
        private bd_banco_cesdeEntities db = new bd_banco_cesdeEntities();
        // GET: api/Cliente
        public IEnumerable<tbl_cliente> Get()
        {
            return db.tbl_cliente.ToList();
        }
```

El modelo

```
public partial class tbl_cliente
    {
        public int DocIdent { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime FechaIngreso { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resulta que en la url había que tener en cuenta las mayúsculas. Era así
http://localhost:49862/Api/Cliente

Ahora funciona.